# Updating database using links and textboxes

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a database that displays the data in three rows.  Firstname, Lastname, and Age.  I have it display in separate text boxes, as shown below.

[image]

Add entry totally works. No problems there.  The real problem is the "Update" and "Delete" links.  Keep in mind that buttons do work, but I'm not suppose to use buttons.  When I click delete, the entry does in fact delete.  And the whole row with the boxes and update and delete are gone.

The problem is that when I click Update after filling in the boxes with other data, this happens.

[image]

Here is the code that I use (at least the important bits)

PHP:

```
if($_GET['type']=='delete'){
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id ='$_GET[id]'";
                    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                    header("Location: form.php");
}if ($_GET['type']=='update'){
                //works but it doesn't seem to just update like before.
                $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET firstname='$_GET[firstname]', lastname='$_GET[lastname]', age='$_GET[age]' WHERE id='$_GET[id]'";
                mysql_query($sql,$conn);
                header("Location: form.php");
}
```

And here is the HTML to do the table and links.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retreve, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

//echo"<form action='form.php' method='post' name='form'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='firstname' value='".$row['firstname']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='lastname' value='".$row['lastname']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='age' value='".$row['age']."'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'> </td>";
//links insead of buttons
echo "<td><a href = 'form.php?type=update&id={$row['id']}&age={$_GET['age']}' id='update'> Update</a> </td>";
echo "<td><a href = 'form.php?type=delete&id={$row['id']}' id='delete'> Delete</a> </td>";
echo"</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

What am I doing wrong for the update message?

PS. It won't let me post more than two pictures. Or pictures.

Comment: Everything's wrong. You're using an outdated api (mysql_), you're not using preparared statements (hurray, sql-injections). You should debug your code, see the values and check if everything's set.

Comment: You are, I hope, aware that by deleting with `$_GET[id]` will enable just about anyone to wipe out any and all data in your table?

Comment: This is just a small project, nothing with any company.  It's just what my teacher wants me to use.

Comment: Does the database table update after filling in the fields and clicking the update link??

Comment: Yes, it does.  The entry looks exactly like the table on the webpage.

Comment: @SanjokGurung what do you think I should do?

Comment: Try this, add this just below your `<?php` tag,
`$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "1";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really keen with mySQL but maybe try concatenating your variables

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id ='" . $_GET["id"] . "'";
```

Same thing with this line

```
$sql = "UPDATE addresses SET firstname='" . $_GET["firstname"] . "', lastname='" . $_GET["lastname"] . "', age='" . $_GET["age"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_GET["id"] . "'";
```

Worth a shot